# Infix.ParseOrUndefined sequence order

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I am using MathNet and trying to parse `2x^2 + x` to epression using

```
Infix.Print(Infix.ParseOrUndefined("2x^2 + x"));
```

but it returns `x + 2x^2`. I want to keep the order of the source because I am going to convert it in LaTex using `LaTeX.Print`.

How can I keep the order when parsing equation?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping an arbitrary order is not possible, unfortunately. By design, in Math.NET Symbolics all expressions are always auto-simplified, and a systematic ordering is a crucial aspect of auto-simplification.

However, if this is more about ordering polynomials by descending exponent instead if an increasing one, or by applying some other systematic order relation at the point of printing the expression, it would certainly be possible to create such an alternative `Infix.Print` (or `LaTeX.Print`) implementation. After all, `Infix.Print` already does quite a few manipulations (other than `Infix.PrintStrict`).

Comment: (I could help providing such a variant)

Comment: I see. thank you. i guess I'll explain my goal. I am creating a simple calculator of definite and indefinite integral in calculus and I want to display it in LaTex, the user's input and the result, which is in MathNet Library and also MathNet.Symbolics is capable of Expanding equation such as `(2x^2 +x)^2` to `x^2 + 4x^3 + 4x^4`. thoug I'm still struggling on equation with function as 'sin(x)' because it has to be differentiate first. I'm sorry if it is off topic.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is easier to discuss this in our forum at http://discuss.mathdotnet.com/. Feel free to open a topic there in the Math.NET Symbolics category.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it is better to discuss it there.

Comment: For reference: http://discuss.mathdotnet.com/t/math-net-symbolics-keeping-the-order/70